# insert text to selected Textbox use Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 textBox and 1 button!
I want to insert text to one of these textboxs. When I click to `textbox_1` and click button, mytext will appear at `textbox_1`. When I click to `textbox_2` and click button, mytext will appear at `textbox_2`.
How can I do this by using JavaScript?
Please help me! I'm new on JavaScript!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

put id's of the two textboxes as `textbox_1` and `textbox_2` and put `onclick='onCLickButton();'` on the `<button>` tag
 and write the following code in the script

```
var text_to_be_inserted = "sample";
function onCLickButton(){
    document.getElementById("textbox_1").value='';
    document.getElementById("textbox_2").value='';
    if(document.getElementById("textbox_1").focused){
        document.getElementById("textbox_1").value=text_to_be_inserted;
    }
    else if(document.getElementById("textbox_2").focused){
        document.getElementById("textbox_2").value=text_to_be_inserted;
    }
    else{
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

***Edited***

Please accept my apologies actually I am used to use these functions as I have my own js file having these functions.

please add `onfocus='onFocusInput(this);'` in the `<input>` tags and add the following code in the script

```
function onFocusInput(object){
    document.getElementById("textbox_1").focused=false;
    document.getElementById("textbox_2").focused=false;
    object.focused = true;
}
```

Comment: It not work, I focus to textbox_2 but when i click button, text appear at textbox_1! Help me!

Comment: When you click the button, focus changes to the button - so neither text box has the focus any more. That's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var index = false;
        var text = "This text shifts to text box when clicked the button";
        
        function DisplayText(){
            if(!index){
                document.getElementById("txt1").value = text;
                document.getElementById("txt2").value = "";
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("txt2").value = text;
                document.getElementById("txt1").value = "";
            }
        
            index = index ? false : true;
        }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="txt1"/>
    <input type="text" id="txt2"/>
    <input type="button" value="Change Text" onclick="DisplayText()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the onFocus() attribute for the INPUT tag - and think about keeping track of what was last given the focus. I'm being a little vague as this sounds a lot like homework.

Comment: thank you! But can you explain more! I have a html form with multiple text field inputs. When I click button, it will insert text to textBox that I focused before, can I use onBlur event for my textBox?

Comment: Clicking the button is the trigger that fills the text box, so no need for onBlur(). If you remember which text box last got the focus - by writing an onFocus() handler for each box and using a global variable - then when you click the button and handle its onClick(), you'll know which box to write the text in.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the prettiest / most delicate solution, but it works and you can build off it to fulfill your needs.

```
<script>
var field = 0;
  function addText(txt){
     if(field === 0) return false;
     field.value = txt;
  }
</script>
```

For a form such as

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="box1" id="box1" onfocus="field=this;" />
<input type="text" name="box2" id="box2" onfocus="field=this;" />
<input type="button" onclick="addText('Hello Thar!');" />
</form>
```